# Find the probability that I get exactly $n$ $1$s if I throw an $m$ sided die $k$ times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say I have an $m$-sided fair die (the sides will have values 1,2,3,.. m) and throw it $k$ times, I want to find the probability to get exactly $n$ $1$'s.

I view the problem as a tree, I throw the die once and the edges lead to every possible outcome with $\frac{1}{m}$ probability and for each outcome I throw the die again and so on.

Define $A$ as the number of ways to get a $1$ the first $n$  times and after that I get no $1$s, which by the counting principle is $$1 \times 1 \times ... (n \ times) \times (m-1) \times (m-1) \times ...$$

Multiply $A$ by $k!$ and divide by $n!$ to get all the possible ways I could get exactly $n$ $1$s,
so the probability of getting exactly $n$ $1$s is $$P=\frac{Ak!}{m^k n!}$$

My question is, is this correct?
If yes is there a better way to write this formula, perhaps by using the notation $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$, factorials etc., if no what is the correct answer?

Also what if the die wasn't fair and I had a different probability for every outcome, what would the formula look like then?

Comment: In a single throw, probability of $1$ is $\frac{1}{m}$ and probability that it is not $1$ is $\frac{m-1}{m}$. Now choose $n$ throws from $k$ where you get $1$ and rest are not $1$. Check binomial distribution.

Comment: Your required probability is $\binom kn (\frac 1m)^n(1-\frac 1m)^{k-n}$ for a fair die and $\binom kn p_i^n(1-p_i)^{k-n}$ for a biased die which has a probability $p_i$ to throw 1.

Comment: Notice that defining getting 1 in a single die throw as a success, the problem is finding the probability of exactly n successes in k independent trials, ergo a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  divide by $(k-n)!$ and define $A$ as $$A=\frac{(m-1)^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}$$
So your formula becomes $$P=\frac{(m-1)^{k-n}k!}{(k-n)!m^kn!}$$
Which can be written as $$P=\begin{pmatrix} k \\ n \end{pmatrix} \left( \frac{1}{m} \right)^n \left(1 -\frac{1}{m} \right)^{k-n}$$
Which is a special case of the binomial distribution $$P=\begin{pmatrix} k \\ n \end{pmatrix} p^n \left(1 -p \right)^{k-n}$$ for $p=\frac{1}{m}$.